# What does this javascript code means?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a form that does changes on the fly and I'm trying to understand it better.

nonetheless, I came upon and input that has this and I was wondering what does this statement means any example would be appreciated. Thank you

```
onclick="if(this.onchange){this.onchange();}"
```

Comment: When you click on the input, if the input has an `onchange` function defined for it, execute that function.

Comment: jonhopkins' answer is accurate.  From a slightly zoomed-out view, what this does is make this input treat a `click` event as a `change` event.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but how does one find out what is the onchange function for that input if it is not define in the input.

Comment: look within the code? i guess you could try to stringify it,

Comment: Changing it to `if(this.onchange){alert(this.onchange);}` will popup a message with the entire code for the onchange function, if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is checking to see if `this` has a function defined as  `onchange`. In javascript, you don't need `if (this.onchange != null)`. If the value is null, undefined, or has an empty string, the value in the if statement returned is false. This is usually a good practice to avoid null reference errors in javascript when you aren't positive that every browser is going to support whatever you're attempting to use. (or other reasons I'm missing now)

For example, when adding a line to output to the console in Google Chrome...

`console.log("output here");`

This may cause errors in other browsers if I remember correctly. A good way to handle this would be to use:

`if (console) { console.log("output here"); }`

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms,

"*If this element has function associated to it's `onchange` event listener, execute it.*".

Answer (score -1):

It's a way to check if it is declared

```
if (typeof this.onchange != "undefined"){
    this.onchange();
}
```